# How to move items between lists in Django

Tags: python, django

Beginner and fairly new to Django here, I have two Django models and I would like to move an item(s) from one to the other. I am using lists to store the items, but for some reason I can't quite figure out why when I try to remove the item from one and move it into the other it is remaining in the previous list. Here is my code:

```
views.py


def add_to_playinglist(request, game_id):
    obj = Playinglist.objects.filter(game_id=game_id, user=request.user.username)

    if obj:
        obj.delete()
        game = Game.objects.get(id=game_id)
        playing_game = Playinglist.objects.filter(game_id=game_id, user=request.user.username)
        return redirect("profile")
    else:
        obj = Playinglist()
        obj.user = request.user.username
        obj.game_id = game_id
        obj.started_on = datetime.now()
        obj.save()
        game = Game.objects.get(id=game_id)
        playing_game = Playinglist.objects.filter(game_id=game_id, user=request.user.username)
        return redirect("profile")


def add_to_playedlist(request, game_id):
    obj = Playedlist.objects.filter(game_id=game_id, user=request.user.username)

    if obj:
        obj.delete()
        game = Playinglist.objects.get(game_id=game_id)
        played_game = Playedlist.objects.filter(game_id=game_id, user=request.user.username)
        return redirect("profile")
    else:
        obj = Playedlist()
        obj.user = request.user.username
        obj.game_id = game_id
        obj.finished_on = datetime.now()
        obj.save()
        print(obj.finished_on)
        game = Playinglist.objects.get(game_id=game_id)
        played_game = Playedlist.objects.filter(game_id=game_id, user=request.user.username)
        return redirect("profile")



def profile(request):
 playinglist = Playinglist.objects.filter(user=request.user.username)
    playinglist_items = []
    playing = 0
    present_in_playinglist = False
    if playinglist:
        for item in playinglist:
            try:
                game = Game.objects.get(id=item.game_id)
                playinglist_items.append(game)
                present_in_playinglist = True
                playing += 1
                
                print(playinglist_items)
            except:
                present_in_playinglist = False

    playedlist = Playedlist.objects.filter(user=request.user.username)
    playedlist_items = []
    finished = 0
    present_in_playedlist = False
    if playedlist:
        for item in playedlist:
            try:
                game = Game.objects.get(id=item.game_id)
                playedlist_items.append(game)
                present_in_playedlist = True
                finished += 1

                playing -= 1
                playinglist_items.remove(game)

            except:
                present_in_playedlist = False
```

```
models.py

class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=500)
    image = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=500)
    genre = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=200)
    platform = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=200)
    developer = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=200)
    publisher = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=200)
    added_by = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"ID# { self.id }: { self.title }"

class Playinglist(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    game_id = models.IntegerField()
    started_on = models.DateTimeField()

class Playedlist(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    game_id = models.IntegerField()
    finished_on = models.DateTimeField()
```

The print statement in my `playinglist` is outputting for each item over each item even when i try moving the item from one list to the next.

Comment: Remember that whatever mucking about you do with your own lists in `playinglist` has absolutely no effect on the database.  If you want to change the database, then you have to do insert and delete operations.  Having said that, you might consider combining those into a single table with an additional field that denotes "played".

Comment: @TimRoberts Hi and thanks for the reply. I've edited the post to include the functions i'm using to add these items to the database. If i were moving an item from my playing list to my playedlist, would I need to then delete that item from my playinglist? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, YOU need to decide that.  If an entry can only be in one list at a time, then yes, you'd need to do that.  However, to reiterate, your `profile` function is not changing EITHER of the master lists.  You are manipulating local lists of records, but playing with those lists doesn't change the database.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for your help. I added some code to delete the item from my `playinglist` after adding it to my `playedlist` which fixed the issue I was having.